# Ford Fulkerson (Maximum flow, minimum cut) using DFS, adjacency list implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I am coding in Python and I am a beginner. I am stuck with Ford-Fulkerson DFS adjacency list code. Somehow, I am not able to get the flow variable assigned correctly. It would be great if somebody can help me here. The problem seems to be with the flow variable in which information is not getting transmitted correctly through different functions.

```
#..............................................................................
Code in Python is as follows:  Answer to the problem1 is 11. Answer to problem2 is 19. 
#...................................................................

'''code'''

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, v1,v2, capacity,flow):
        self.from1 = v1
        self.to1 = v2
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.residual=[]
        self.flow = flow
        
        
    def isResidual(self):
        return self.capacity == 0
    
    def remaining_capacity(self):
        
        kk = self.capacity - self.flow
        print("Line 22, inside remaining capacity, kk,self.flow",kk,self.flow )
        return self.capacity - self.flow
        
    def augment(self,bottleneck):
        print("Line 24, INside Augment, self.flow,self.residual.flow,, self.from1, self.to1, self.capacity ", self.flow,self.residual.flow, self.from1, self.to1, self.capacity )
        self.flow =+ bottleneck
        self.residual.flow =- bottleneck
        #self.residual.capacity =- bottleneck
        #self.capacity =- bottleneck
        #self.residual.capacity =- bottleneck
        
        
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, numvertices):
        self.m = numvertices
        self.graph = []
        self.initialize_empty_flow_graph()
        
    def initialize_empty_flow_graph(self):
        
        for i in range(self.m):
            self.graph.append([])
            
    def add_edge(self, v1,v2,capacity,flow):
        e1 = Edge(v1,v2, capacity,flow)
        e2 = Edge(v2,v1,0,flow)
        
        e1.residual = e2
        e2.residual = e1
                self.graph[v1].append(e1)
        self.graph[v2].append(e2)
        
class ford_fulkerson:
    def __init__(self, Graph, numvertices):
        #self.n = numvertices
        self.n = numvertices
        self.s = self.n - self.n # source index
        self.t = self.n - 1  # sink index
        self.visitedToken = 0
        #self.visited = list(range(0,self.n))
        self.visited = list(range(100,n+100))
        #self.visited = list(range(-self.n, 0))
        self.minCut = [False]*self.n
        self.maxFlow = 0
        
    def solve(self,Graph):
        
        while True:
                
            print("-------Line 293---------, in solve")
            f = self.dfs(Graph, self.s, flow = float("inf"))
            print("Line 79, bottleneck value in solve", f)
            self.visitedToken = self.visitedToken+1
            self.maxFlow = self.maxFlow+f
            
            print("Line 83: self.maxFlow and F",self.maxFlow, f )
            if f == 0:
                break
            
    def dfs(self,Graph, node, flow):
        print("-----------a-------------------")
        #print()
        
        if (node == self.t):
            print("Line 92,flow", flow)
            return flow
        
        self.visited[node] = self.visitedToken
        edges = Graph.graph[node]
        for edge in edges:
            print("Line 97:Inside for loop,edge.from1,edge.to1,edge.capacity",edge.from1,edge.to1,edge.capacity)
            if (edge.remaining_capacity()>0 and self.visited[edge.to1] != self.visitedToken):
                print("Line 99:Inside if condition, for loop")
                bottleneck = self.dfs(Graph,edge.to1, min(flow, edge.remaining_capacity()))
                #flow = edge.flow
                print("Line 102, bottleneck",bottleneck)
                if (bottleneck > 0):
                    
                    edge.augment(bottleneck)
                    
                    return bottleneck
        return 0
    
            
#.......................
# Problem 1: # Answer is 11.      

n = 4
g = Graph(n) # nodes+1source node +1 sink node

s = n-n # source node is n-2; 
t = n-1 # sink node is n-1
flow = 0
g.add_edge(s, 1, 7,flow)
g.add_edge(s, 2, 12,flow)
g.add_edge(1, 2, 9,flow)
g.add_edge(1, t, 10,flow);
g.add_edge(2, t, 4,flow);

ford = ford_fulkerson(g,n)
ford.solve(g)

#.......................
# Problem 1: # Answer is 19

n = 6
g = adjacency_set_graph(n, directed = False) # nodes+1source node +1 sink node
s = n-n # source node is n-2; 
t = n-1 # sink node is n-1
flow = 0
g.add_edge(s, 1, 10,flow)
g.add_edge(s, 2, 10,flow)

g.add_edge(1, 2, 2,flow)
g.add_edge(1, 3, 4,flow)
g.add_edge(1, 4, 8,flow)
g.add_edge(2, 4, 9,flow)
g.add_edge(4, 3, 6,flow)

g.add_edge(3, t, 10,flow);
g.add_edge(4, t, 10,flow);
ford = ford_fulkerson(g)
print(ford.n,ford.s,ford.t)
ford.solve(g)
```

Comment: The `=+` "operators" look suspicious -- they get parsed as `self.flow = (+bottleneck)`.

Comment: This operation is working correctly. The problem is that once dfs traverse all the nodes and flow is calculated for them, then a particular edge should remember that which is not happening. Also, I am not sure that self.residual.flow is getting utilized inside dfs.